# Better way to parse from regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am doing the following to get the movieID:

```
>>> x.split('content')
['movieID" ', '="770672122">']
>>> [item for item in x.split('content')[1] if item.isdigit()]
['7', '7', '0', '6', '7', '2', '1', '2', '2']
>>> ''.join([item for item in x.split('content')[1] if item.isdigit()])
'770672122'
```

Would would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a regular expression, you could just split by the double quotes and take the next to last field.

```
u="""movieID" content="7706">"""
u.split('"')[-2]  # returns: '7706'
```

This trick is definitely the most readable, if you don't know about regular expressions yet.

Your string is a bit strange though as there are 3 double quotes. I assume it comes from an HTML file and you're only showing a small substring. In that case, you might make your code more robust by using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) such as:

```
import re
s = re.search('(\d+)', u)  # looks for multiple consecutive digits
s.groups()  # returns: ('7706',)
```

You could make it even more robust (but you'll need to read more) by using a DOM-parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume `x` looks like this:

```
x = 'movieID content="770672122">'
```

Regex is definitely one way to extract the content. For example:

```
>>> re.search(r'content="(\d+)', x).group(1)
'770672122'
```

The above fetches one or more consecutive digits which follow the string `content="`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could do something like the following if your string is like the below:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'movieID content="770672122">'
>>> re.search(r'\d+', x).group()
'770672122'
```